# Submit form values using controller and model in magento frontend module

Tags: magento-1.9, database, forms

I am building an module and need to process a form but am having troubles getting the variables to POST and am just redirected to the same page. The form looks like this :

```
    <form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline');?>" method="post">
  <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" />
  </form>
```

i have controller

```
    public function remarksdeclineAction()
{

              $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');

              echo $message;
          echo "hi";
           exit();    
    }
```

now how to insert form value in table. anyone can help me

Comment: @Qaisar Satti .. thanks for editing my question can you reply

Answer (score 0):

```
public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
             $model = Mage::getModel('OrderApproval/process');
             $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
             $model->setMessage($message); //your table column name will be mmessage
             $model->save();

              echo $message;
          echo "hi";
           exit();    
    }
```

read this how models work

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-5.html
https://www.pierrefay.com/en/magento-training/model-database-tutorial.html

Comment: $model->setMessage($message);    $message is my table column name

Comment: `setMessage` in `Message` column name should be `message` . ` $message` will be value

Comment: sorry i did not get you setItemcomment($message) where itemcomment is column am i right

Comment: First letter will be capital of columm after set

Comment: now i am using this function public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
             $model = Mage::getSingleton('OrderApproval/process');
    $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
             $model->setItemcomment( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );
    $model->save();
        echo $message;
    echo "hi";
     exit();   
    }

Comment: Is it saving the values im database

Comment: public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
             //$model = Mage::getSingleton('OrderApproval/process');
    $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
             //$model->setItemcomment( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );
    //$model->save();
        echo $message;
    echo "hi";
     exit();  
         
    }

Comment: i was getting error setitemcomment

Comment: after comment i am getting data on controller now controller is calling

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="orderapproval-item-form" class="orderapproval-hidden" action="<?php echo Mage::helper->getUrl("orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline/");?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="message" class="orderapproval-disabled" value="<?php echo $this->__('Enter decline reason'); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->__('Decline'); ?>" />
</form>
```

Please check your redirection url in form action. add just need to set url in small char.

Thanks

Comment: now i put form url in small char but its still not working <?php echo Mage::helper->getUrl("orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline");?>

Comment: your controller call or not??

Comment: no controller is not calling

Comment: <?php echo Mage::helper->getUrl("orderapproval/customercart/remarksdecline/");?> print this line

Comment: did not anything

Comment: public function remarksdeclineAction()
{
             //$model = Mage::getSingleton('OrderApproval/process');
    $message = $this->getRequest()->getParam('message');
             //$model->setItemcomment( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );
    //$model->save();
        echo $message;
    echo "hi";
     exit();  
         
    }

Comment: now controller is calling but data is not saving in database

Comment: can you update you question with full controller action

Comment: i have updated my question kindly check and reply me i am waiting your response

Comment: i am getting form data on controller ...

Comment: What is field name in your table for message??

Comment: itemcomment is column in sales_quote_item_order

Comment: i have form and controller and create a column in sales_quote_item_order table i did not create model

Comment: now controller is calling properly

Comment: you need to create model 1st for this table. i think sales_quote_item_order its your custom table

Comment: yes its custom table how to create a model for it can you tell me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50815/discussion-between-er-sarvesh-v-tiwari-and-ajay-patel).